# MCV jQuery .ajax returning 'Not Found' and 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to post a file using jQuery but it returns 'Not Found' and 'undefined'.

html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="JQDocumentUploadTB">Optional - Upload Invoice (PDF)</label>
        <div class="form-control-static">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <span>Add File...</span>
                <input type="file" id="JQDocumentUploadTB" name="JQUpload" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```
<script>


$('#JQDocumentUploadTB').on('change', function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var vdata = new FormData();
            for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                vdata.append('file' + x, files[x]);

            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UploadInvoice/UploadingFile",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: vdata,
                success: function (result) {

                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                    var err = status + ' - ' + p3 + ' - ' + p4;
                    if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                        err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                    alert(err);

                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
        }
    }
});
```

Controller

```
 <HttpPost()>
    Public Async Function UploadingFile() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of JsonResult)
        Try
            For Each file As String In Request.Files
                Dim fileContent = Request.Files(file)
                If fileContent IsNot Nothing AndAlso fileContent.ContentLength > 0 Then
                    ' Return ModalSuccess("File is here")
                    Return Json("Got here")
                End If



            Next

            'Return ModalError("No file was uploaded!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Return ModalError("There was an error uploading the file")


            Return Json("Upload failed")
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. What is Not Found and what is undefined? When and where do you receive that error? What's the network response headers for `UploadInvoice/UploadingFile` when you make that POST?

Comment: Post your controller and action code.

Comment: Posted controller code - message comes from alert(err);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Ajax.BeginForm worked fine with that URL...

```
@Using (Ajax.BeginForm(Nothing, "UploadInvoice/PartialPost", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST"}, New With {.id = "FormUpload"}))
```

I had assumed that the same would apply to the jQuery Ajax call. Silly me!  Changing URL to

```
url: "../UploadInvoice/UploadingFile",
```

Fixed the issue and it now posts back correctly - but I foresee this being an issue when the app is deployed but I can sort that headache out when I get there

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to not hard-code your url, instead use:

```
'@Url.Action("UploadingFile","UploadInvoice")'
```

Comment: I thought that @ was the equivalent of webforms server side controls. Can I use that in an Ajax JavaScript?

Comment: It is the Razor engine syntax to embed server side code. Did you choose to use Razor syntax for this project? Either way, I think the better approach to use server side code let it generate url for you dynamically, instead of hard-coding.